# Can I get invidually sorted Mapper outputs from Hadoop when using zero Reducers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a job in Hadoop 0.20 that needs to operate on large files, one at a time.  (It's a pre-processing step to get file-oriented data into a cleaner, line-based format more suitable for MapReduce.)

I don't mind how many output files I have, but each Map's output can be in at most one output file, and each output file must be sorted.

- If I run with numReducers=0, it runs quickly, and each Mapper writes out its own output file which is fine - but the files aren't sorted.
- If I add one reducer (plain Reducer.class) this adds an unnecessary global sort step to a single file, which takes many hours (much longer than the Map tasks take).
- If I add multiple reducers, the results of individual map jobs are mixed together so one Map's output ends up in multiple files.

Is there any way to persuade Hadoop to perform a map-side sort on the output of each job, without using Reducers, or any other way of skipping the slow global merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing global sorting is to have a custom partitioner and  do range partitioning for your reducers. For this to work you have to know the range of your mapper output  key. You could divide your key range into n buckets where n is the number of reducers. Depending on the bucket the key maps into, the mapper output  gets routed to a specific reducer.

Output of each reducer is sorted. Collection of all reducer output is globally sorted, because of the range partitioning. All you have to do is to take the reducer output files in the same order as the 5 digits in the file name.

One thing to watch out for is the skew in your key distribution, which will result in uneven reducer load in the cluster. This problem can be alleviated if you have distribution information i.e., histogram of the key. Then you could make your bucket length unequal and each one holding approximately same number of keys.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Combiners aren't going to globally sort your data - they are basically a cache to partially aggregate reducer data.

Normally you don't want to sort each mapper's output separately, but if you do, why not add the mapper file id as part of your output and use a custom partition function so the output of each mapper is partitioned separately, and hence sorted separately, so the outputs of any mapper is always in a single file? You'd also probably want to group by the file id, so you would get the sorted output of each input file separately.

I am curious, why do you want to sort mapper output separately anyhow?

Another thought, Hadoop is actually going to do a mapper-side sort ("the shuffle") if you sort your output, so you probably could have it not delete those temporary files if you did run with many reducers.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a partial solution - running with many reducers for speed, but ignoring their output & instead keeping the temporary sorted map files.

I want the mapper output files as input to future jobs, had been hoping to keep them sorted as they have chronological structure that makes the sorted files easier to use.  

However I'm now going down the route of using a different mapper output format which is easier to query when not strictly sorted - feels like a better fit for MR anyway.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the data consumed by your mappers is not significantly large, you can avoid getting it collected and keep track of the data in a local, sorted data structure. Then, you can do the writing/collecting of the sorted data in the cleanup/finalization step.

Answer (score 0):

See Ben's comment below -- this doesn't work.  I'll leave this wrong answer here so that we at least know what doesn't work.

I believe that's what a `Combiner` would do for you.  I have never used them myself, but http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/mapred_tutorial.html states (section Payload / Mapper):

> Users can optionally specify a
>   combiner, via
>   JobConf.setCombinerClass(Class), to
>   perform local aggregation of the
>   intermediate outputs, which helps to
>   cut down the amount of data
>   transferred from the Mapper to the
>   Reducer.

My reading of this is that if you specified an identity reducer as the combiner, then each mapper's output should be sorted.

Comment: I do have "job.setCombinerClass(Reducer.class)" in place.  It doesn't seem to take effect when reducers is zero.  

From Mapper.java:

<p>If the job has zero reduces then the output of the <code>Mapper</code> is directly written to the OutputFormat without sorting by keys.</p>

So I suppose I'm asking whether there's a way to circumvent this, or get the same effect by other means.

Comment: Too bad.

So, could you not output anything in the mapper's `map` call, but simply stash the values to be collected in memory (use enough mappers to make sure this doesn't get too big).  Then in the `cleanup` call sort the values yourself and output them then.

Comment: Yes - think I will have to sort it there myself, though memory per mapper might be a problem... Thanks for the input.